# ie7 cant loop over string with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops, internet-explorer-7, ie7.js

Anyone knows why this isnt working in IE7 and how I can make it work?

```
var test = "hello";
for (var i = 0, len = test.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(test[i]);
}
```

or see http://jsfiddle.net/75Cqt/

Comment: @IgorDymov: Drat, was kind of hoping it wasn't a duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support indexing into strings with `[i]`, you have to use `charAt(i)`. E.g.:

```
var test = "hello";
for (var i = 0, len = test.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(test.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `test.charAt(i)` in place of `char[i]`